# If statement based on whatever the previous view controller was

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

Here is what I go so far:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (preivousViewController isEqualToString:@"...") 
    {
        if ([self.filteredArray count] == 0)
            self.person = self.users[indexPath.row];
        else
            self.person = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row];
        self.mugshot = cell.imageView.image;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SelectPerson" sender:self];
    } else {
        if ([self.filteredArray count] == 0)
            self.person = self.users[indexPath.row];
        else
            self.person = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row];
        self.mugshot = cell.imageView.image;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectVisitee" sender:self];
    }
}
```

It looks messy, that's why im trying to fix it up (that `previousViewController` part is just made up to show you what I want to try to do).

What im trying to say is: If how you got to this view was via this segue, or from that view controller with the name `suchandsuch`, then preform this segue or that segue. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: you shouldn't use the name of the previous view controller. the controller triggering the segue to this controller should set a flag (probably an enum) to specify which type of 'editing' you're doing and then you should use that to decide what to do. your other code is also identical in each branch of the if so it should be done before the if...

Comment: You can remove the code duplication since the first 5 lines in both branches are exactly the same. Just move that part in front of the actual if-block.

Comment: can I not use the previous segue used to get to this view to identify which segue to use next?

Comment: Yes, but use an `enum` or `BOOL` to identify which view controller it was.  Look at the duplication and see what varies between the two blocks.  Basically the only conditional logic is around the name of the next identifier; i.e. `NSString *nextVC = _previousViewControllerWasSomething ? @"SelectPerson" : @"SelectVisitee";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the previous ViewController of the stack from the Navigation Controller.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           if ([self.filteredArray count] == 0)
                self.person = self.users[indexPath.row];
            else
                self.person = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row];
            self.mugshot = cell.imageView.image;

            //Not the viewcontroller name string. Use the ViewController class name
            if ([self backViewController] == YOURVIEWCONTROLLER) 
           {

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SelectPerson" sender:self];

        } else {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectVisitee" sender:self];

        }
}
```

Use this below method,

```
- (UIViewController *)backViewController
{
    NSInteger numberOfViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;

    if (numberOfViewControllers < 2)
        return nil;
    else
        return [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:numberOfViewControllers - 2];
}
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: Great solution, however why omit the braces from the first if-statment. Just makes reading not as clear...