# If statement based on the previous View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have been trying to convert this code from Obj-C to Swift : [If statement based on whatever the previous view controller was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34432800/if-statement-based-on-whatever-the-previous-view-controller-was/34433444#34433444) (almost exact the same question)

In other words, I would like to go back to the View Controller that the user came from, either MainViewController or SearchTableViewController choosing between two unwind segues.

**My question is: How do I write the same functional code as in the link above, but in Swift instead of Obj-c?**

This is my translation so far (not working, can't get rid of the errors)

```
//Method
func backViewController() -> UIViewController {
        let numberOfViewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.count
        if numberOfViewControllers < 2 {
            return nil
        }
        else {
            return self.navigationController!.viewControllers[numberOfViewControllers - 2]
        }
    }


    if  self.backViewController() == MainViewController {
//Back to MainViewController
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackMain", sender: self)
    }
    else {
//Back to SearchTableViewController
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackSearch", sender: self)
    }
```

**EDIT/PROGRESS:**

I have changed the function to `backViewController() -> UIViewController?` and it get rids of the errors there. But a new error occurs in the if-statement, regarding the Binary operator '=='

```
"Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIViewController?' and 'MainViewController.Type'.
```

Comment: Change `-> UIViewController` to `-> UIViewController?`.

Comment: Use this link to convert it to Swift https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/   Please upvote this if it works

Comment: "Not working" and "all help is much appreciated" are not questions. Too broad. Asking us to translate your code for you is not a question either.

Comment: I started out trying it, but it doesn't run. Thank you anyways @Nik

Comment: I have edited the question and it now has a clear question! @matt

Comment: The question is closed. Asking for a complete translation into Swift is not a legitimate use of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is Swift. Only an Optional can be `nil`. You are trying to return a UIViewController from your `backViewController` method. UIViewController is not an Optional, so it cannot be `nil`. If you need it to be `nil`, make it an Optional: `UIViewController?`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the first errors in the function/method. But please see my comment on the answer above (question from @Sam M), a new error has occured in the if-statement. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to be able to return `nil` you need to make the return type optional.
   Replace `func backViewController() -> UIViewController`
   with `func backViewController() -> UIViewController?`
2. Since you're comparing different viewControllers you can not use '=='. You should try to cast it as the viewController you want.
   replace this

   ```
       if  self.backViewController() == MainViewController {
   //Back to MainViewController
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackMain", sender: self)
       }
       else {
   //Back to SearchTableViewController
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackSearch", sender: self)
       }
   ```

   with

   ```
       if let _ = self.backViewController() as? MainViewController {
   //Back to MainViewController
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackMain", sender: self)
       }
       else if let _ = self.backViewController() as? SearchTableViewController {
   //Back to SearchTableViewController
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AuthorBackSearch", sender: self)
       }
   ```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. I followed your advice and got rid of the errors regarding the Method/function (1.). But now when I have replaced my old if-statement with yours (2.) a new error occurs. "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIViewController?' and 'MainViewController.Type' @Sam M

Comment: @Mate See my edited answer.